# Insert form data into database in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-2.3

I want to insert my form data into database using cakephp. I created form.ctp file in layouts folder. Now how can I insert form values to database in `form.ctp` file?

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<form action="../users/register" method="post">
<p>Please fill out the form below to register an account.</p>
<label>Username:</label><input name="username" size="40" />
<label>Password:</label><input type="password" name="password" size="40"
/>
<label>Email Address:</label><input name="email" size="40"
maxlength="255" />
<label>First Name:</label><input name="first_name" size="40" />
<label>Last Name:</label><input name="last_name" size="40" />
<input type="submit" value="register" />
</form>
</html>
```

Comment: Follow CakePHP docs and you will understand that. The logic will be handled in your method.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<form action="../users/register" method="post">
<p>Please fill out the form below to register an account.</p>
<label>Username:</label><input name="users[username]" size="40" />
<label>Password:</label><input type="users[password]" name="password" size="40" />
<label>Email Address:</label><input name="users[email]" size="40"
maxlength="255" />
<label>First Name:</label><input name="users[first_name]" size="40" />
<label>Last Name:</label><input name="users[last_name]" size="40" />
<input type="submit" value="register" />
</form>
</html>
```

and save by

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) { 
    $this->User->save($this->request->data);
}
```

OR 
save your data without change form by

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) { 
    $this->request->data['User'] = $this->request->data;
    $this->User->save($this->request->data);
}
```